# Wand equivalent of ImageMagick "convert -append"

Tags: wand

I would like to write the equivalent of

```
convert left.jpg right.jpg +append ouput.jpg
```

I found something like it in another post:

```
files = glob('*.jpg')
with Image() as orig: # create empty Image object
    for f in files:
        page = Image(filename=f)
        orig.sequence.append(page)
    orig.save(filename='result.pdf')
```

and changed it to

```
with Image() as orig: # create empty Image object
            page = Image(filename='left.jpg'); orig.sequence.append(page)
            page = Image(filename='right.jpg'); orig.sequence.append(page)
            orig.save(filename='output.jpg')
```

but the output file just shows the first file, rather than a file with the images side-by-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first attempt was completely wrong, it probably makes an animated image. Provided the two images are the same size, this will do it:

```
with Image() as blankimage:
    with Image(filename = 'imageA.tif') as imageA:
        w = imageA.width; h = imageA.height
        with Image(filename = 'imageB.tif') as imageB:
            blankimage.blank(w*2, h)
            blankimage.composite(imageA, 0, 0)
            blankimage.composite(imageB, w, 0)
            blankimage.save(filename = 'output.tif')
```